# ¿Que significa este error en SQL server 2008R2 y como corregirlo?

Tags: sql-server

Estoy ejecutando un .dll desde SQL server me dice algo de permisos de usurio pero el resto no se que significa.

Por favor alguien me colabora de ser necesario via **anydesk** lo agradesco

```
Unexpected exception : System.Security.SecurityException: Error de solicitud de permiso de tipo 'System.Net.DnsPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
   en System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   en System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
   en System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   en System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(String host, Int32 port)
   en StoredProcedures.Command(SqlString serviceName, SqlString cmmd)
Acción que generó el error:
Demand
El tipo del primer permiso que generó un error era:
System.Net.DnsPermission
La zona del ensamblado que generó el error era:
MyComputer
```

Comment: Ese no es un error de SQL Server, en todo caso sería un error del dll. Sería bueno que des un poco más de contexto.

Comment: Perdona amigo el DLL esta Perfecto de hecho me ha funcionado el mismo en todos los demas SQL que he armado sin error alguno solo aqui me presenta dicho error

Comment: Por ser un tema de permisos **"SecurityException"**, **"DnsPermission"** puedes probar ejecutando como administrador.

Comment: No dije que el DLL estuviera mal, sólo que el error lo generó el DLL. Sin contexto de que se está haciendo, nadie podrá ayudarte.